# Copy range of cells with arguments

Tags: vb.net, spreadsheet

```
Function rangecopy()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:d4").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")
End Function
```

The above function works fine but i want the above function to work with arguments so that i can mention the address of the rows and columns or a range which are to be copied.

The range can contain any kind of data or all data types.

Any help is really appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

```
Function rangecopy(byval SourceSheet as string, byval SourceRange as string,byval DestSheet as string,byval DestRange as string)
    Worksheets(SourceSheet).Range(SourceRange).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets(DestSheet).Range(DestRange)
End Function
```

You can name your variables anything you want, I try to have them make sense.